# Applying validation class ng-valid delayed for one step after real state change

Tags: validation, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I have two input controls in reactive form on the page (see [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-j6ujrc?embed=1&file=pages/login/login.ts)). 
Here is main template part:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>PIN code</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="pinVisible" ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>hidden control</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="pin" #pin></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

Both should be valid when content only 4 chars long. When I edit “hidden control” it fills other control (“PIN code”) with new masked value with following code:

```
this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
  pinVisible: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)]],
  pin: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)]]
});
this.pinVisibleControl = this.loginForm.get('pinVisible');
let pinControl = this.loginForm.get('pin');
pinControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
  console.log(value);
  this.pinVisibleControl.setValue(new Array(value.length).fill('*').join(''));
  this.pinVisibleControl.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
  console.log(`PIN visible status: ${this.pinVisibleControl.status}`);
});
```

The problem is the validation state classes (ng-valid particularly) are applied to “PIN code” not right after change of control value, but only in next change cycle (when I enter fifth letter). So green valid indicator on “PIN code” appears only after next change (usually when it contains 3 or 5 letters, not 4).
Any suggestion how to apply validation classes right after value change?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `this.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();` instead of`.markAsTouched()`. Marking as dirty/touched will only take effect when you check it's validity.

Comment: I added `this.pinVisibleControl.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true});` after .markAsTouched() but looks like it does not help. I tried different values for its parameters.